# How to manage RWeka packages in restrictive desktop?

Tags: r, weka, decision-tree

first ever I post but I use stackoverflow a lot to solve my doubts. Now, after expending a couple of days just searching, I decided to ask myself.

I am new with R and with RWeka. I am having some troubles using and managing wekafiles (or the weka packages). The issue is more about my restrictions on using the computer I've got. I'm on a "floating" desktop so in order to install/use all R-packages, I need to change all paths to a private drive in that desktop. I've done that with the R libraries and so far so good. my problem comes when using certain commands from RWeka.

For example, when using CostSensitiveClassifier as seen in the examples I got from internet:

```
csc <- CostSensitiveClassifier(Species ~ ., data = iris, control = Weka_control(`cost-matrix` = matrix(c(0,10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0), ncol = 3), W ="weka.classifiers.trees.J48", M = TRUE))
```

What I get is the following error:

> Error in .jcall (classifier, "v", "buildClassifier", instances): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component

Using the commands in a normal desktop, I don't get that error, everything works. So, definitely, my problem is the way the "floating" desktop is designed...

After searching, my guess was that I needed to change WEKA_HOME to point somewhere in my private disk. So what I did was:

```
Sys.setenv(WEKA_HOME="P:/<username>/RuserLibrary/wekafiles")
```

But I know that's not enough. Another guess is that I need to get the Weka packages in my private drive. I've read the paper [Rweka: Odds and Ends](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/vignettes/RWeka.pdf) and I try to see which packages I've got and try to install them in my private disk so I used the commands:

```
WPM("list-packages", "installed")
```

Where I get the message:

> "Unable to download repository zip archve (Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 403 for URL: http/weka....."

```
WPM("list-packages", "available")
```

I get:

> "Local package list is missing..."

```
WPM("install-package", "J48Consolidated")
```

I get:

> Local package list is missing, trying a cache refresh to restore...
>   [WekaPackageManager] Package J48Consolidated at version Latest doesn't
>   seem to exist!

So, what is happening? How can I get the packages working? Can anyone bring me some light about the errors?
As you see, I'm playing around with things I don't fully understand yet. One option would be to talk with the administrator and get permissions but I need to understand first what is happening in order to tell him what I need.
I would really appreciate any advice or help here.

Thank you!

Comment: Problem is that you need to run R as a admin to install such packages. You should try to specify youre own library. http://www.stat.osu.edu/computer-support/mathstatistics-packages/installing-r-libraries-locally-your-home-directory

Comment: Thanks. I do have RWeka installed in my own library in the private disk "RuserLibrary". I wouldn't know how to indicate that when trying to get the Weka packages with WPM(), I assumed that it would be done automatically when setting the WEKA_HOME variable?
Unfortunately, I can't run R as admin (restrictive environment...).

Comment: I dont know about Weka maybe you can also specify library inside the WPM function

Comment: Thanks, I'm searching about that too. It should have done it when setting WEKA_HOME to point my local library but it's not doing it, although I think it's cause it cannot access the URL of the Weka packages in first place so I just contacted my administrator if I can get the access, I'll try that and see if I still get the error.

Comment: Alright Good luck:) hope you'll get it fixed

Comment: @FabiolaFernández have you fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately not and I have now moved to another job so cannot investigate this further...